# How to mask the URL with htaccess in zend 2

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have a project, it's done in zend. After user registration, confirmation email will send to users email. Inside email there is a link to click for confirm the user registration. `http://www.test.de/domain-user/registration/confirm-email/ASDDSDWDWWDA321` I need to shorten this url to `http://www.test.de/ASDDSDWDWWDA321` How can it possible with htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^domain-user/registration/confirm-email/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)(/|)$ /$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I would definitely not do that but rather use a route. If your code is of a defined length and always uppercase for instance, creating a route is more than easy.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it possible to redirect `http://www.test.de/ASDDSDWDWWDA321` to `http://www.test.de/domain-user/registration/confirm-email/ASDDSDWDWWDA321` using htaccess?